# How to show categoy of the post in recents posts widget wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have a recent posts widget on my wordpress website's right sidebar that is displaying recent posts from multiple post types. I want this widget to also show the post type or category of the post. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this within the loop `get_the_category($id)`

To do this manually (i.e by creating your own function), add this in a function and call it when you need it

```
<ul>
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <li><?php get_the_category(the_ID())->name; // caetgory name ?></li>

        <?php 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please explain where do I put this line?
Also I don't want to modify core of the wordpress

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yemi, I know how can I register short codes and call them or whatever, but what I want was a more like setting in the existing widget or something else, without touching the code files.
Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Code For that recent post in sidebar.php

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args ); ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $recent['ID'] ); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $recent['ID'] ); ?>">
                    <div class="recent_post_meta">
                        <span>
                        <?php $category_detail = get_the_category( $recent['ID'] );//$post->ID
                            foreach( $category_detail as $cd ){
                            echo $cd->cat_name;
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                        <div class="post_side_title">
                            <?php echo get_the_title( $recent['ID'] ); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>

    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```